# Is there a one-dimensional subshift of positive entropy s, all of whose sub-subshifts also have entropy s?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, entropy, symbolic-dynamics

A subshift is a subset $X$ of $A^\mathbb{N}$ or $A^\mathbb{Z}$ (with $A$ finite), such that $X$ is topologically closed and closed under the shift operation.  The shift operation is defined by $\sigma(\{x_i\}_{i\in G}) = \{x_{i+1}\}_{i\in G}$ (where $G = \mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$).

The entropy of a subshift is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log(|B_n|)}{n}$ where $B_n\subseteq A^n$ is the set of length-$n$ strings which appear in some element of the subshift.

Is there a one-dimensional subshift $X$ of positive entropy s, all of whose sub-subshifts $Y\subseteq X$ also have entropy s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  If $X$ is minimal (every orbit is dense) then the only subshift $Y\subset X$ is $X$ itself.  The Jewett-Krieger theorem allows the construction of minimal subshifts with positive entropy, which therefore have the property you desire (albeit somewhat vacuously).  Googling "minimal subshifts with positive entropy" brings up [this paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~bruin/papers/recdim.pdf) by Henk Bruin, which includes such a construction and also gives two references to earlier constructions:

1. Hahn and Katznelson, "On entropy of uniquely ergodic transformations", Trans. AMS **126** (1967) 335-360
2. C. Grillenberger, "Construction of strictly ergodic systems I. Given entropy", Z. Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie **25** (1972/1973) 323-334

Comment: Is it false for every non-minimal  SFT?

Comment: If X is a positive entropy SFT, then there is always a subshift Y contained in X such that 0 < h(Y) < h(X). If X is transitive, construct Y by adding a word to the list of forbidden words. If the word you add is long enough, Y will still be a positive entropy SFT. But its entropy is smaller than that of X since the unique MME of X gives full weight to every open set. For the general case when X is not transitive, first replace X by one of its transitive components.